# Apache Ignite Cache using shared memory for caching data

Tags: caching, shared-memory, ignite

From docs/sources it seems that Apache Ignite may use shared memory for communication purpose only (as interconnect between instances running on the same node, instead of sockets).

Is it possible to use large shared memory segments for caching actual Apache Ignite data?

Comment: Can you refer the documentation you are referring to as a link?

Comment: i checked the code and also it is mentioned in few places like https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/network-config
 see 'setSharedMemoryPort'

Answer (score 1):

Shared memory is used only for communication. However, you can use off-heap memory to store the data: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/off-heap-memory

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, but am i right that even for off-heap memory ignite will still malloc() memory space and we can't use existing shared memory segments ( for example mmap'ed in-memory filesystem) to store data?